# php Graph Api How to upload multiple photos with only 1 status

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I try this docs

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/#photos

```
POST /me/cookbook:eat?
  recipe=http://www.example.com/recipes/pizza/&
  image[0][url]=http://www.example.com/recipes/pizza/pizza.jpg&
  image[0][user_generated]=true&
  image[1][url]=http://www.example.com/recipes/pizza/pizza2.jpg&
  image[1][user_generated]=true&
  access_token=VALID_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

and try on graph explorer using parameter *image[0][url]* for image url, but it not work
But if I use *url* parameter, it will work.

What I need is upload multiple photo using 1 status.

This is the example

https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=701584806542084&id=696202487080316

Thank you

Comment: not yet get solution @deepu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ["Custom Stories" Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph).
Specifically checkout the "Publishing Actions" section [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/v2.0#publish) and notice that the "images" field is designated as allowing "multiple values".